# Hypernym for "today", "upcoming", and "past"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, time, hypernyms

I am creating an app where people can look for yard sales in their area. They will be able to look for sales going on today, coming up in the near future, and sales that are past.

Here is an example sentence, used when the user does not select a ____ by which to filter:

> "You must select at least one ____."

As you can see, *Time*, or *Date* seem a little awkward in that sentence.

Comment: How about **duration**?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "time", and the three hyponyms are quite typically the past, the present, and the future, rather than "past, today, and upcoming". Can you explain your motivation for using such a strange combination of words instead of the idiomatic, ubiquitous ones? What is the context? Where is the example sentence? Are you writing an app and can't think of what to label a drop-down with? Are all three even nouns at all? It very much seems you are trying to use a weird mix of a noun, a modifier, and an adverb, for reasons unspecified. Please elaborate.

Comment: How about [***timeline***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/timeline)?

Comment: How about **time period**?

Comment: 'Time' is a mass noun that can be made discrete with a determiner (such as 'a'), so 'a time' covers both a point or a period in time.  'Today' is commonly adverbial, but it is more noun than adverb, and 'the past' works fine as a noun phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use ***time range***.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/range):

> ***range***
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.3** The **period of time covered by something** such as a forecast.
>
> The accuracy of the method varies within reasonable limits depending
>   on the ***time range*** of the forecast for different conditions.

Comment: This is good.  You could also use a similar phrase, *time frame*.

Answer (score -1):

How about 'Point in Time'?

(Is this perhaps for a header on a form, incidentally?)

Having seen your edit, you might also consider 'time point'.